# animation / keyframes not working in Firefox (starting CSS animation via JavaScript)

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations, keyframe

This code works in *current* chrome and internet explorer, but not in *current* firefox (UPDATED Code with [unnecessary -moz prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507589/animation-keyframes-not-working-in-firefox#comment-49091238)):

```
@-moz-keyframes sh-tada {
  10% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sh-tada {
  10% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@keyframes sh-tada {
  10% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

.sh-tada {
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation: sh-tada 2s linear 1;
  -moz-animation: sh-tada 2s linear 1;
  animation: sh-tada 2s linear 1;
}
```

The element does not appear at all.

Alas, none of the other identically entitled questions help in this case...

## ADDITION / HINT

Maybe my problem lies not within the code above, but in the question

**how is the CSS animation fired?**

The element in question is simply turned on with `...style.display='inline'`. For Chrome and IE, that seems to be ok. But is it not ok for firefox?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: "current", i.e. 38.0.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add rule for firefox. checkout following code

```
@-webkit-keyframes sh-tada {
  10% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes sh-tada {
  10% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@keyframes sh-tada {
  10% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

.sh-tada {
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation: sh-tada 2s linear 1;
  -moz-animation: sh-tada 2s linear 1;
  animation: sh-tada 2s linear 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh_Mahajan! I updated the question. I had wanted to imply that this old recommendation (-moz) does not help unfortunately. See @web-tiki's comment...

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are missing the definition for Mozilla Broswer keyframes.

```
@-moz-keyframes sh-tada {
10% {
    opacity:1;
}
80% {
    opacity:1;
}
100% {
    opacity:0;
}
}
```

and the moz-animation

```
.sh-tada {
  -moz-animation:sh-tada 2s linear 1;
}
```

Add these to your css and it should work.

Comment: it must a very old version of Firefox then as it should support keyframe animations without prefixes [since version 16](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation)

Comment: Thanks @brance! I updated the question. I had wanted to imply that this old recommendation (-moz) does not help unfortunately.

Comment: I'm late on this, but did you solve the problem? Try to remove the 80% keyframe, maybe the transition is too fast, and extend the animation duration, something like 10s, it should be easier to see what happened (especially with the current Firefox animation tools)...